# Bing Maps V8 - How can I rotate map in Bird's Eye view?

Tags: rotation, maps, bing-maps, bing

I am upgrading from Bing Maps V7 to V8 and rotating the map from JS doesn't work anymore. I have been trying with this piece of code:

```
map.setView( { heading:90 } );
```

This works if I change the source URL for the map library to V7. And I see that the "setView" function and the "heading" option still exist in V8.

Here's an article about how to do it in V7:
https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/03/28/rotating-bing-maps/

Answer (score 1):

Bing Maps V8 currently doesn't have Birdseye. A new birdseye experience is being introduced to V8 within the next few months. This new experience has a lot of new imagery which uses a different format from the old birdseye experience. Given that the imagery that is in V7 is very old and is a major point of DSAT, it was decided to hold off on adding birdseye to V8 until the next experience and data is available.

Comment: Thanks, but I figured this out in another post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38611054/no-more-birds-eye-view-in-the-bing-maps-v8-api/38614006

Comment: Update: Birdseye was added to Bing Maps V8 at the beginning of April in the experimental branch. It is now in the main release branch. A button is not in the map type dropdown at this time as the team is waiting until more of the new imagery is processed and available in the control.

Answer (score 1):

I did some more research and two undocumented things have changed.

1. map.setView() does not respond to a full options object anymore.
   Example:

   `var options = this.map.getOptions();`

   `options.heading = 90;`

   `map.setView(options);`

It now needs the heading and other changed fields manually specified to reflect any changes.

```
map.setView({heading: 90});
```

2. `map.setView({heading: xx})` no longer accepts negative values as valid so you must manually submit heading values for any clockwise rotations so that it corresponds to the positive heading value.
   Thus, `map.setView({heading: -90})` was previously smart enough to know that is equivalent to `map.setView({heading: 270})`, but now must be submitted to the API as a positive value.

Similar to the first example, I have some legacy code for resetting the map back to original lat/lon and heading that now needs a second setView() call in order to update.

```
var options = this.map.getOptions();
options.zoom = this.initialZoom;
options.center = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(this.lat, this.lon);
options.heading = this.heading = 0;
this.map.setView(options);
this.map.setView({heading: this.heading});
```

Must call setView another time so that the new heading is actually applied.