# No more bird's eye view in the Bing Maps V8 API?

Tags: bing-maps, deprecated, bing-api

It appears that Bird's Eye View is no longer available in V8. **Can anyone confirm** that this is actually the case or if there is any way of still using Bird's Eye View in the new version?

Microsoft's documentation about this is very poor, so I just pieced the information together from various sources.

**For example:**

1.
In their [MapTypeId Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712700.aspx) the 'birdseye' option doesn't exist anymore.
This used to exist in V7.

2.
Bing's own [snippet generator](http://www.bing.com/maps/embed/SnippetGenerator.aspx) for embeded maps has an option to add the Bird's Eye View, but when checked it only adds a "View bird's eye" link under the map which redirects you to www.bing.com with the Bird's Eye View selected.

[image]

3.
When embedding a V7 map, the Bird's Eye option is available in the navigation bar:

[image]

In V8 the option doesn't exist:

[image]

---

**UPDATE:** I have received an email reply from Microsoft stating that Bird's Eye View isn't yet available in V8, but will be at a later point. Here is their reply:

> "Birdseye imagery is currently not available in Bing Maps V8. The
>   migration guide doesn’t mention Birdseye imagery but it does state
>   that anything that isn’t mentioned is planned to be in the V8 control.
>   Currently the Birdseye imagery in Bing Maps V7 is very old, some
>   images are 10+ years old. This is one of the highest points of
>   customer DSAT that we have. We have collected a lot of new imagery,
>   but it still needs to be processed so that it can be exposed to the V8
>   map control.
>
> Additionally we are creating a new user experience around
>   Birdseye as the current experience isn’t as fluid as it can be and is
>   an issue for many. Processing the imagery takes several months to do.
>   Developing the new user experience will also take a few months. We are
>   currently planning to have the new Birdseye experience in V8 by the
>   Microsoft Build conference which is near the end of March 2017 (8
>   months from now)."

Comment: March 2017 has come and gone and Bird's Eye is still not available in v8.

Comment: Update: Birdseye was added to Bing Maps V8 at the beginning of April in the experimental branch. It is now in the main release branch. A button is not in the map type dropdown at this time as the team is waiting until more of the new imagery is processed and available in the control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not available because Microsoft are renewing the images for it.
It will be available again in the future.

[See this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c6148a9a-f2b4-481f-b1af-dc041153436a/bing-map-v8-map-birds-eye-mode-is-not-avilable?forum=bingmapsservices)

Comment: Ok, this sounds reasonable. But how do you know this? Is there an official statement about it anywhere?

Comment: You are right. I have just received an email reply from Microsoft about this. I've updated my post with their reply.

Answer (score 0):

Even though birdseye is listed now in the enumeration doc for v8, this morning (Monday) I discovered that, even thought it seemed to be working Friday, though now that I think about it seems like it was more aerial than bird's eye, my map was rendering in some sort of messed up default view that didn't obey viewbox settings. I changed the view type to aerial and it works again. The really odd thing is that IE and Edge were messed up, but Chrome was not.